# What kind of dancing style is shown on AronChupa's Little Swing video?

Tags: genre, music-video, dancing, swing

What kind of dancing style is shown on AronChupa's Little Swing [music video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ipvEIZMMILA)?

Comment: Downvoter, isn't dancing part of music appreciation?

Answer (score 5):

In the video, there are several dances represented.  But generally this is swing dancing and they teach it at swing dance clubs.  The first paired-dances you see in the video are variations of lindy hop (a member of the 8-counts) and in the latter you see east coast swing (a member of the 6-counts.)

I personally prefer the Lindy Hop because the steps are symmetrical and therefore are less likely to cause problems with my ankles when doing the more complex moves.  The east coast swing is generally taught by beginner dance teachers because it gets people doing the tuck turns early on.  Advanced dancers freely transition between 6-counts and eight-counts.  And if you are keeping count, blues and jazz typically have a beat structure of 48 instead of 32 (normal trance music has the 32 count structure.  House music is a hybrid of 48 and 32.  European producers prefer 32 but American producers will sometimes or oftentimes use 48.)  This count structure allows dancers to divide between verses both the eight count and the six count nicely.

At some moments in the video, you see the Charleston and there are tap and jazz solos.